# If else when grabbing JSON in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, if-statement, model-view-controller, ember.js

I am new to Ember.js but I've gotten good so far, what I'm having a problem with now is that I am grabbing JSON to a template using this `Route.Extend`:

```
App.AppsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.$.getJSON('/api/apps.php').then(function(data) {
      return data;
    });
  }
});
```

What I want now is a `if-else` conditional to tell when I have a JSON array greater than 1. 
This is what I put in my template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="apps">
    <p class="heading-table">Apps</p>
    <a class="submitPrimary" {{action 'addModal' 'newapp' model}}>Add new</a>

    {{#if data}}
      <table class="apps-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Quota left</th>
            <th>Installs</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        {{#each}}
          <tr {{#link-to 'app' this}}
              <td>{{id}}</td>
              <td>{{name}}</td>
              <td>{{quota.used}} <b>/</b> {{quota.remaining}}</td>
              <td>{{installations}}</td>
              <td class="user">@{{owner}}</td>
              <td>{{status}}</td>
          </tr>
          {{/link-to}}
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
      </table>
    {{else}}
      <center>
        <h2>No apps created</h2>
        <p class="read-more-mini">Click <a href="#" {{action 'addModal' 'newapp' model}}>here</a> to create a new app.</p>
      </center>
    {{/if}}
  </script>
```

The if-statement would render the table and the else would render the center-tag and that inside it. When I run my code I get no errors in my console, but the `else` is rendered. 
Even though that `data` is set to be a JSON response.

Why is this happening and how could I fix this `if-else` conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is required to check against `model` eg.

```
{{#if model}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/welarego/1/edit

Also something irrelevant but i think the first tag of the `tr` element in `<tr {{#link-to 'app' this}}` is not closing.
If it is needed to have the same effect e.g. have a clickable row then try,

**hbs**

```
....
{{#link-to 'app' this tagName="tr"}}

              <td>{{id}}</td>
              <td>{{name}}</td>
              <td>{{quota.used}} <b>/</b> {{quota.remaining}}</td>
              <td>{{installations}}</td>
              <td class="user">@{{owner}}</td>
              <td>{{status}}</td>

{{/link-to}}
....
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xezajeyo/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the answer, life-saver! Oh, typo, moved the {{/link-to}} inside the <tr> now, around all the <td>'s. Cheers!

UPDATE:
Thank you for the help with the updated answer including the hbs as well!

Comment: @Jack i'm glad it helped, also just added something you may need.